# Code Coverage for Pull Request for Bitbucket Cloud

Tags: bitbucket, code-coverage, pull-request, bitbucket-cloud

I found the following addon for Code Coverage status directly in a Pull Request, that can be integrated with Bitbucket Server.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218271/code-coverage-for-bitbucket-server

Is there any similar addon for showing Code Coverage status directly in a Pull Request, that can be integrated with Bitbucket Cloud?

I do not see it in the list of addons below:

https://bitbucket.org/account/user/[user_name]/addon-directory

Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

You did not miss anything. It isn't there.

Comment: Can I request them to add one?